# Mysql - unable to update integer entry

Tags: mysql, sql-update

For some reason, I am not able to update an entry in my table with `smallint` value.

Attached is the screenshot where, at first, I display a row with `sim_id=127`. Next, I successfully update entry `notes`. However, when I try to update the entry `group`, an error pops up. According to documentation, this syntaxis should work correctly.

Let me know if I need to include more information. Here is the server version:

```
innodb_version          | 5.5.55-MariaDB-38.8 |
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| slave_type_conversions  |                     |
| version                 | 5.5.57-MariaDB      |
| version_comment         | MariaDB Server      |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64              |
| version_compile_os      | Linux
```

Thanks,
Mikhail[image]

Comment: group is a reserved word in MySQL

Comment: No images please. Use formatted text. As Strawberry mentioned, `Group` is a reserved keyword. Use some other name instead of that.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I did not that, I am new to sql world. Should I close my question? The thing is that the error message doesn't give me a hint that I am using a reserved word.

Comment: @MikhailGenkin Here is a list of all the Keywords (including Reserved) in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html